# List of available Svelte live templates "code snippets" in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, svelte, jetbrains-ide

I am using JetBrains IDEs (PyCharm, WebStorm, etc.) to edit Svelte components with `.svelte` file extension.

The plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12375-svelte clearly offers some live code templates. If I type `if` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it expands it to `{#if }{/if}`.

However, I could not find on the plugin page or in the IDE settings itself the list of what autocompletes are supported and what are the keywords.

Would anyone with more JetBrains IDE experience give a hint?

Comment: I see none as well. Therefore from my end I may only suggest to make a new `.svelte` file and manually invoke code completion there (`Code | Code Completion | Basic` -- `Ctrl+Space` here on Windows keymap), e.g. after `{` -- Svelte entries will have appropriate icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per LazyOne's suggetion you can see some of templates if you type `{#` (the marker of Svelte template directive) and press Ctrl + Space / Cmd + Space

[image]

There are not many of them according to this.